# How to add rectangle above scrollable view in Accessibility service?

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I create my own TalkBack and want to see the same functionality

**The story:**

If the view is static, then I can get all the elements just by getting all the children like this

```
val child: AccessibilityNodeInfo = rootInActiveWindow

deepChild(child)

...

fun deepChild(child: AccessibilityNodeInfo){
    for (i in 0 until child.childCount) {
        deepChild(child.getChild(i))
    }
    ...
}
```

After I get the coodinates and draw it in WindowManager by adding through `windowsManager.addView(view, params)`

**The problem:**

If the view is not static (for example has recycler view), then the rectangle keep the same position, but view will be moved

**What i want ?**

How to add this rectangle above the view and keep the position while scrolling ?

**PS** I know that TalkBack has open source code, but the code is crazy and I don’t want to die 10 hours after the start

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a general-purpose way to do this. You just need to listen for updates to the UI and redraw the box. There will be some lag.

TalkBack handles this by using AccessibilityFocus, which requires turning on ExploreByTouch. The focus highlight for accessibility focus is drawn in the app process, so it follows the views much more consistently.

Comment: Is the Accessibility Focus library open source or is it an internal TalkBack module ?

Comment: Accessibility Focus is handled by the Android framework.

Comment: You mean just like android:focus attribute ?